# Pandas read_json(orient="table") returns NaN if the column is an integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue when converting a DataFrame to JSON and back whilst using orient="table".

If a list is loaded into a DF and then exported as JSON using `to_json(orient="table")` the schema output includes the column name as an `int` which appears to be the cause of the issue.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

# List
arr = ["123"]

# Create the dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(dataframe)

# Get the table as a schema
dataframe_table_schema = dataframe.to_json(orient='table')
print(dataframe_table_schema)

# Load the DataFrame from the json object
dataframe = pd.read_json(dataframe_table_schema, orient='table')
print(dataframe)
```

**Output**

```
     0
0  123

{"schema": {"fields":[{"name":"index","type":"integer"},{"name":0,"type":"string"}],"primaryKey":["index"],"pandas_version":"0.20.0"}, "data": [{"index":0,"0":"123"}]}

     0
0  NaN
```

To work around the issue we can loop over the fields `dataframe_table_schema.schema.fields` and check if the field name is an integer if it is cast to a string and then dump the object to a JSON string.

```
import pandas as pd

# List
arr = ["123"]

# Create the dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(dataframe)

# Get the table as a schema
dataframe_table_schema = dataframe.to_json(orient='table')

# Load the schema into a dict
dataframe_table_schema_modified = json.loads(dataframe_table_schema)
# Loop over the fields
for field in dataframe_table_schema_modified.get("schema").get("fields"):
    # Get the column name
    column_name = field.get("name", "")
    if isinstance(column_name, int):
        # Cast the field name to a string
        field["name"] = str(column_name)
#  Dump the object to a string
dataframe_table_schema_modified = json.dumps(dataframe_table_schema_modified)
print(dataframe_table_schema_modified)

dataframe = pd.read_json(dataframe_table_schema_modified, orient='table')
print(dataframe)
```

Please could someone confirm if this is a bug or if there is a way to handle this correctly?

### **pd.show_versions()**
INSTALLED VERSIONS

commit           : None
python           : 3.8.0.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Linux
OS-release       : 5.8.0-1041-aws
machine          : x86_64
processor        : x86_64
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : C.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 0.25.2
numpy            : 1.17.3
pytz             : 2019.3
dateutil         : 2.8.0
pip              : 19.3.1
setuptools       : 41.6.0
Cython           : 0.29.13
pytest           : 5.2.2
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : 2.2.1
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.2
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
html5lib         : 1.0.1
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : 2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
jinja2           : 2.10.3
IPython          : 7.8.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.8.1
bottleneck       : 1.2.1
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
matplotlib       : 3.1.1
numexpr          : 2.7.0
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.0
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : None
pytables         : None
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.3.1
sqlalchemy       : 1.3.10
tables           : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : 1.3.0
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.2

Comment: looks like this is the same issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38256

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between your field and data.

Notice in "fields", the column name is 0 i.e. an integer:

```
"fields":[{"name":"index","type":"integer"},{"name":0,"type":"string"}]
                                                   #^integer
```

But in "data", the column name is "0" i.e. a string:

```
"data": [{"index":0,"0":"123"}]
                    #^string
```

You can correct this by specifying the column names while constructing your DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["123"], columns=["A"])
js = df.to_json(orient="table")
df = pd.read_json(js, orient="table")

>>> df
     A
0  123
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. As the schema output was generated using the pandas function `to_json(orient='table')` it looks like it is a bug.

I am unable to specify the columns as you suggested because the DataFrame is created dynamically. To give you a little context we are creating a DataFrame dynamically from a datasource we do not have control over.  Once the DataFrame has been created we store it so it can be referenced later, the DataFrame is being stored as a json string using `to_json(orient="table")`.

Do you have any other suggestions to ensure the column and key match?

Comment: Do the dataframe columns have integers and strings ? You could try doing `df.columns = list(map(str, df.columns))` before calling `to_json`

Comment: I will have to check whether both are used, I believe your solution should work as `orient="table"` does appear to be treating the auto index's as strings (based on the example in my question).  I will run some tests post my findings. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help! If that does solve your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green check mark next to it! :). That helps keep the "unanswered" thread clean.